# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failure when using model::with in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel eloquent ORM and I have some relationships defined as such:

```
class Item extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'IV00102';
    protected $primaryKey = 'ITEMNMBR';
    protected $trimmableAttributes = ['ITEMNMBR', 'PRIMVNDR'];

    public function backorderQuantities(){
        return $this->hasOne(BackorderQuantity::class, 'ITEMNMBR', 'ITEMNMBR')->where('SOPTYPE', 5);
    }

}
```

and the relational model as :

```
class BackorderQuantity extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'SOP10200';
    protected $primaryKey = 'ITEMNMBR';
    protected $trimmableAttributes = ['ITEMNMBR', 'SOPNUMBE', 'SOPTYPE', 'QUANTITY', 'QTYREMAI'];

    public function item(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Item::class, 'ITEMNMBR', 'ITEMNMBR');
    }

}
```

The problem arises when I try and fetch the data with the defined relationship:

`Item::with('backorderQuantities')->where('PRIMVNDR', Auth::user()->vendor_id)`

Doing so results in this Error:

`[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'X123RECORD231' to data type int`

I can make this work without eagerloading doing 2 queries and then looping through and checking the relationship like so:

```
foreach ($objects as $view) {
            if($view->backorderQuantities){
                // do things
            }  
        }
```

but this presents a number of issues for me and is more like a bandaid than a legitimate fix. I would like to know if there is a fix to this or if the compatibility between an SQL server and MSSQL server just won't fly.

Comment: I want to note, the relationships have been tested and work, its an error specifically related to the eager loaded method

Comment: The error mentions you're trying to convert a string `X123RECORD231` to int... Can you share a sample of the data?

Comment: The data is coming from MSSQL server and sent and received as a string. Again this is a compatibility issue not a data issue. data comes back fine in a normal query without the "with". but I need the eager loading to work

Comment: Can still send an example of the data contained in the model of the relation? maybe this will help to see the problem clearly

Comment: So the problem after a weeks worth of testing has seemed to resolve itself. I can't say exactly how because it came out of the blue, but it is resolved, and the data was never changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug has been resolved. I'm still fairly certain it was a compatibility issue, but this is one of those weird instances where a code somehow resolves itself. I will update this answer if/when I isolate and come across the problem again in the future.